# iOS System Volume Control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, system-sounds

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound() is playing my sounds using ringer volume.

I want them to play according to system volume instead.

How to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [AVFoundation Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) to play your sounds. Look into the [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067)
class.

Comment: That consumes a lot of memory. No way.

Comment: @GSchv - Really? Apple recommended it at the WWDC10. Oh well, I tried.

Comment: @Moshe - I play several sounds simultaneously. My game is very very popular. I'd need to create like 5 AVAudioPlayer objects, which would make my game lag. Any suggestions?

Comment: Create the sound player objects ahead of time (in your delegate perhaps) and pass them to the view when necessary?

Comment: I was thinking Audio Queues. Do you know anything about Audio Queues?

Comment: @GSchv - Nope, sorry. I imagine the concept is similar though. If you find out about them, let me know. (starred)

Comment: Use OpenAL. There's a nice example / useable sound engine here: http://www.71squared.com/2010/01/latest-sound-manager-class/