# How to control volume in iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I would like to control volume and mute in iOS app.
My app can playback YouTube Video in swift3 and I don't know how to control the video sound.

Does anyone have ideas to do that ?

Comment: are you using `YTPlayer` for playing youtube video?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414301/ios-accessing-device-hardware-audio-volume-control

Answer (score 1):

You can use MPVolumeView. Just create MPVolumeView and add in subview. This gives you a UISlider for volume. Using that slider you can change the volume.

For reference check the following links.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview

[iOS: Accessing device hardware audio volume control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414301/ios-accessing-device-hardware-audio-volume-control)